# Meaning of the double dash in options

Tags: find, options, syntax

I've read that all multi-character command options must be preceded by a double dash (`--`). But many flags for the `find` command (e.g. `-name` or `-type`) are preceded by only one dash. Why is that?

Comment: This convention was initially created by GNU and used by ``getopt_long``. Not all unix tools use it. java and X are notable exceptions

Answer (score 2):

It's just a GNU style convention to precede double dashes for long options, not a 'must'. GNU programs using only one dash for long options are (mostly) from the time where the GNU C library did not yet support `getopt_long` to parse arguments in today's fashion.